# Symfony - disable exception detailed trace

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I am using **Symfony 6** and I want to show an error trace only in case the environment variable is set to `true`.

My `.env` file:

```
IS_DEVELOPMENT_ENV=true
```

And then in `framework.yaml` file:

```
framework:

    error_controller: "%env(resolve:IS_DEVELOPMENT_ENV ? 'debug' : 'error')%"
```

But for now, I do not see any changes. Does anyone know if this could be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a configuration value to enable or disable DEBUG:

```
APP_DEBUG=0 // or 1
```

The `error_controller` variable allows to override the default error Controller (https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller), I am surprised you don't have any error by setting a simple string.